# PHP DOMDocument load and loadXML

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I'm trying to load large (12MB) XML document. Online XML validator says that this document is valid. DOMDocument::load loads it just fine, but something goes wrong with DOMDocument::loadXML:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('document.xml');
echo $doc->saveXML(); // Works fine

...

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$text = file_get_contents('document.xml'); // fopen / fread gives the same result
$doc->loadXML($text); // Error!
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

The error message looks like that:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): internal errorExtra content at the end of the document in Entity, line: 126617 in ... on line ...
```

The error message points to loadXML function call. XML document looks ordinary, nothing interesting at line 126617. What do I do wrong? XML document can be downloaded from here: http://rghost.ru/download/56485804/089074ffefa7338c53ef40df59c4792e73f4a0c2/document.zip

Comment: Moreover, if I'll do file_put_contents after file_get_contents, and then use $doc->load for this new file, everything also works just fine.

Comment: it's not an error message. It's a **warning**. Did you look at what's at line 126617 in your file?

Comment: OK, it's warning, but document wasn't loaded (parsed). The "echo" following after loadXML displays nothing. And there is nothing special at the line 126617, nothing special that wasn't somewhere before in this document. You can download it and check by yourself.

Comment: When DOMDocument loads markup, it throws a number of content-related warnings and errors by default. To obey this, use [libxml_use_internal_errors](http://us1.php.net//manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php)

Comment: Hey Miloshio, thanks for the advice, I've ran it with internal errors enabled, but I didn't find any new information: http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?75xofm65raz2

Comment: @nyan-cat: FYI: Unable to reproduce. Which PHP version and which libxml version are you using?